# Вопрос по SQL запросу

Tags: c#, sql

Вот скажите я имею этот код

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO news (title, body) VALUES(" + textBox1.Text + "," + richTextBox1.Text + ");", cnt);
```

И у меня ошибка постоянно типо нету такой колонки, а если я использую этот

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO news (title) VALUES(\"" + title + "\");", mysqlCon);
```

То все нормально, так можно вставлять сразу много запросов?

Comment: поле body  в таблице news есть?
richTextBox1.Text случайно не содержит кавычек?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А если так?

```
"INSERT INTO news (title, body) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + richTextBox1.Text + "');"
```

Comment: А можно ещё и на UPDATE запрос?

Comment: UPDATE news SET title = '" + string1 + "', body = '" + string2 + "' WHERE .... "

Используйте ORM вместо этих конкатенаций, или параметры для запросов на худой конец.

Comment: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE news SET date='" + textBox2.Text  + "' title = '" + textBox1.Text  + "', body = '" + richTextBox1.Text  + "' WHERE id = " textBox7.Text + ");");

Где здесь ошибка?

Comment: "', title = '"

Comment: Все равно ошибка...
Connection must be valid and open.

Этот код я использую

>`MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE news SET sitename = '" + null + "', keywords = '" + textBox2.Text + "', description = '" + textBox3.Text + "', seconds = '" + numericUpDown1.Value + "', domen = '" + textBox1.Text + ");");`

Comment: Ну так нужно соединение с базой создать.

Comment: Дак оно создано и открыто...

Comment: Судя по ошибке проблема именно с соединением.

Comment: > Дак оно создано и открыто...

Тогда, насколько я понимаю, в команде должен быть указан идентификатор подключения в качестве параметра. Или же подключение должно быть отмечено как дефолтное.

Answer (score 1):

правильная строка SQL:

> INSERT INTO news (title,body) VALUES("какаятострока1","какаятострока2");

значит, нужно правильно записать ее в C#. т.е. вспомнить как в строку правильно записать кавычку. кавычка в строке выглядит так:

> "

соответственно:

> str = "INSERT INTO news (title,body) VALUES("какаятострока1","какаятострока2");" ;

и в варианте с переменными:

> str = "INSERT INTO news (title,body) VALUES(""+STR1+"",""+STR2+"");" ;